# Can't insert data into database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I can't seem to insert the data into my database. I was wondering if I used the SCOPE_IIDENTITY correctly. I just want to insert these data into my database without having to key in the PurchOrderId manually.

In my BllPurchaseOrder.cs file:

```
public int InsertPO(String PurchName, String PurchDesc, int SuppId)
    {

        StringBuilder sql;
        SqlCommand sqlCmd;
        int result;

        result = 0;

        sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.AppendLine("INSERT INTO PurchaseOrder(PurchName, PurchDesc, SuppId, CreateDate, SentStatus)");
        sql.AppendLine(" ");
        sql.AppendLine("VALUES (@PurchName, @PurchDesc, @SuppId, @CreateDate, @SentStatus)");
        sql.AppendLine(" ");
        sql.AppendLine("SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)");
        sql.AppendLine(" ");
        SqlConnection conn = dbConn.GetConnection();
        try
        {
            sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), conn);

            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PurchName", PurchName);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PurchDesc", PurchDesc);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateDate", DateTime.Now);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SuppId", SuppId);
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SentStatus", "Sent");

            result = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            errMsg = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        return result;
    }
```

In my InsertPO.aspx.cs:

```
int result = 0;

        string PurchName = tbPurchName.Text;
        string PurchDesc = tbPurchDesc.Text;
        int SuppName = int.Parse(ddlSuppName.SelectedValue);

        BllPurchaseOrder po = new BllPurchaseOrder();
        result = po.InsertPO(PurchName, PurchDesc, SuppName);

        if (result > 0)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Insert Successful!'); </script>");
            Response.Redirect("~/ViewAllPO.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Insert NOT Successful'); </script>");
        }
```

Comment: Also need a `;` between `INSERT` and `SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)` commands

Comment: @JenishRabadiya It works with **Insert Statement** too

Comment: What you have in `dbConn.GetConnection()`? I don't see `conn.open()` anywhere?

Comment: I guess you forget to write con.open()

Comment: Any error? or just nothing in the db?

Comment: @Shaharyar There's no error. It just bring me to "Insert NOT Successful"

Comment: No, check database if your record is inserted there or not? It seems that **RedFilter** is right, you need to use `ExecuteScalar` to get the value.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I stored the connected in a method in another file.

Comment: @Shaharyar There's no record inserted in the database. It gives me an error when i used ExecuteScalar.

Comment: When you were using `ExecuteNonQuery` the records were inserting at that time? And what is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Use ExecuteScalar rather than ExecuteNonQuery, since you are selecting a value that you want returned.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code is fine and should work,

But the problem is that you forgot to open the connection.

So please open the connection.

Regards.